# Why doesn't my function produce output

Tags: c++, class, cout

I'm doing a C++ assingment for a class and I haven't used C++ in a decade so this might be something I'm missing that is simple; however ,I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a class I defined with a function that is producing no output; it looks like it's not even running and I don't have a clue why.  Could someone point out my problem to me?

Issue:  `cout` from the function `getwords` of the class `readwords` doesn't display any results.

Here is my class:

```
class readwords {
    private:
            char c;
            //string aword;

    public:
            void getwords(std::istream& file) {
                            cout << "I got here" << std::flush;
                    /*while(file.good()) {
                            cout << "I got here\n";
                            c = file.get();
                            if(isspace(c)) cout << "\n"; //continue;
                            if(isalnum(c)) {
                                    cout << c; //aword.insert(aword.end(),c);
                            }
                    }
                    */
            }
};
```

Which is being called from my main:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "lab1.h"

using namespace std;
readwords wordsinfile;
words wordslist;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 2 ) {
            // Looks like we have no arguments and need do something about it
            // Lets tell the user
            cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] <<" <filename>\n";
    } else {
            // Yeah we have arguements so lets make sure the file exists and it is readable
            ifstream ourfile(argv[1]);
            if (!ourfile.is_open()) {
                    // Then we have a problem opening the file
                    // Lets tell the user and exit
                    cout << "Error: " << argv[0] << " could not open the file. Exiting\n";
                    exit (1);
            }

            // Do we have a ASCII file?
            if (isasciifile(ourfile)) {
                    cout << "Error: " << argv[0] << " only can handle ASCII or non empty files. Exiting\n";
                    exit(1);
            }

            // Let ensure we are at the start of the file
            ourfile.seekg (0, ios::beg);
            // Now lets close it up
            ourfile.close();
    }

    // Ok looks like we have past our tests
    // Time to go to work on the file

    ifstream ourfile2(argv[1]);
    wordsinfile.getwords(ourfile2);

}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Your code in the `argc != 2` case neither flushes nor exits and just lets the code go on to de-reference the non-existent `argv[1]`.

Comment: `argv[1]` is defined.  True I'm not looping through all possible args because I haven't gotten that far yet however I've confirmed that `argv[1]` is set when being used for `ifstream ourfile2(argv[1]);`

Comment: Make the constructor for `readwords` or `words` is not terminating. Can you post a self-contained compilable example demonstrating the error?

Comment: Yeah, there is no output, I would think it would print the cout? `g++ -g -o lab1 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp lab1.cpp
[ryan@sherwood lab1]$ ./lab1 lab1.h
[ryan@sherwood lab1]$`  Sorry about the formatting but there is no output.  I do not know why.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error (I get the output), but I had to modify the code before it would compile. If you give us a minimal complete example, maybe we can find the bug.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but why do the `readwords` class have the `c` variable? It would be better as a local variable inside the `getwords` member function.

Comment: main.cpp [link](http://pastie.org/4614678)

Comment: lab1.h [link](http://pastie.org/4614685)

Comment: lab1.cpp [link](http://pastie.org/4614688)

Comment: Makefile [link](http://pastie.org/4614691)

Comment: Sorry for the multiple post, but a side note how do I do a newline in the comment section?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg your correct, I've been moving things around trying to figure this out.

Comment: Instead of posting the links as comments, why not edit the post to put them there?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a debugger. Most IDEs (NetBeans, Code::Blocks, etc) provide an interactive interface with gdb.

Comment: I've used gdb, no help.  There is no error, just no output either.

Comment: Using debugger, you can execute your program step-by-step, seeing a variables values and current execution position.

Comment: With gdb I put a break on main then did next until completion.  I didn't see any variables so maybe there is another way (I'm sure there is) to use gdb I just can't seem to find it.  It doesn't show me any insight into the lab1.cpp file.

Comment: To see the variable, you must know it's address and ask GDB to show this memory block. For step-by-step execution, you must put next breakpoint before you continue execution. So It's very hard and inefficient to use GDB without front-end. I've already suggested you to use an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I just compiled and ran your code, but nothing wrong with the code itself,
except that I needed to include  to use the 'cout' method.
"I got here" has been successfully displayed in my ubuntu machine.
What is your execution environment? You should check it first.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be redefining my own class.  When actually coding the function I needed to use:

```
in readwords::countwords(std::istream& file) {
 ....
}
```

Once doing this output produced fine.